# opencart price slider dont read discounts

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

i have module price slider, but example product price 15$ and have discount and new price for it 5$, and then slider is set to show products who costs more than 5$ it didn't show my product because slider get price from sql product table and didn't get from other table from discount.

my code:

```
        //Filter products based on price slider
if ((isset($this->session->data['lower']))&&(isset($this->session->data['higher'])))
{
$sql .= " AND p.price >='". $this->session->data['lower'] ." ' AND p.price <='". $this->session->data['higher'] ."'" ;
}
//Filter products based on price slider
```

how to add to this code to min cost info from table "product_special"?

module: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=13278&filter_search=price%20slider&filter_license=0

Comment: You will probably need to do a JOIN in your query. Can you post the full $sql string and the schemas for the products and product_special tables?

Comment: em, i don't know where to find it on Opencart

Comment: This is about a third party extension. Questions about modifying third party extensions shouldn't be a part of SO - You should contact the extension's developer(s) directly to ask for support. If You think You cannot wait for the support no longer and are willing to do the modifications Yourself make sure You are not breaking any license (mostly when extension is paid).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a user contributed extension for OpenCart. If you read through *all* of the comments at the bottom of the Price Slider Module page, the developer of the extension chameleonengineering says it is only based on original price and that making it also use special prices is under development.

I would recommend commenting there yourself or contacting the developer directly so they know there is more demand for this feature. Otherwise you are left with the options of modifying the code yourself (which requires a good understanding of the table schemas you're dealing with), or finding a different extension.